# Making a box plot of the proportion of cells in each cell types in two groups

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have number of cells in three cell types T, B, M in a Seurat object

For two groups of patients, cancers and controls like

```
> table(Idents(pbmc), pbmc$samples)
   
    PN0252_0001 PN0252_0002 PN0252_0003 PN0252_0004 PN0252_0005 PN0252_0006 PN0252_0008
  T        3550         568         136         268        1835           2        1678
  B         136         129          11          25         133           0         203
  M         120          22          18          26         159           0          59
> dput(table(Idents(pbmc), pbmc$samples))
structure(c(3550L, 136L, 120L, 568L, 129L, 22L, 136L, 11L, 18L, 
268L, 25L, 26L, 1835L, 133L, 159L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1678L, 203L, 59L
), .Dim = c(3L, 7L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("T", "B", "M"
), c("PN0252_0001", "PN0252_0002", "PN0252_0003", "PN0252_0004", 
"PN0252_0005", "PN0252_0006", "PN0252_0008")), .Names = c("", 
"")), class = "table")
>
```

Patients `PN0252_0001`, `PN0252_0002`, `PN0252_0003`, `PN0252_0004` are controls

and `PN0252_0005`, `PN0252_0006`, `PN0252_0008` are cancers

I want to look at the difference of the proportion of cells in each cell type between cancer and control

But I am confused for getting proportion should I divide the number of cells on total cells in the object or total cells in each group

Basically I need a box plot like although here numbers are not correct

[image]

Comment: This looks like a ggplot with a facet added to it. What have you tried?

Comment: What I plotted here is what I have tried but I am not sure about the proportions

Comment: Your boxplot seems correct. What do you think is wrong about it?

Comment: I don't know proportion of T cells for example, I should divide the number of T cells in each patients on the total number of cells or total cells in controls and cancers separately

Comment: The answer to that depends on the question you're asking and what you wish to showcase. In any case, only you can answer it, we can't do that for you.

Comment: Ram RS as always your comments are extremely helpful . Thanks a million

Comment: @mahta-mira, are you able to write up your solution as an answer, then mark it as a selected answer? This will help the StackExchange bots work out what's going on.

Comment: At the moment I am not certain if my solution is correct :(